# Crash of Release build in WCF service call with custom security binding and invalid credentials

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, crash, xamarin.android

I've implemented custom UserName Password & WS-Security in my Xamarin.Android application as described here: http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/03/15/username-password-amp-ws-security-with-silverlight.aspx

Everything works great in DEBUG mode (with or without valid credentials) and also works great in RELEASE until the user provides invalid credentials. As soon as the invalid credentials provided an application crashes without any chance to prevent this crash. Here is what I can see in Application Output:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.Xml.XmlException: Text node cannot appear in this state.  Line 1, position 1.
[MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x00028>
[MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) <0x0003f>
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () <0x00027>
[MonoDroid] at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () <0x0003f>
[MonoDroid] at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) <0x0003b>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.c4ebb548-a354-4444-bc7d-3e13bebb1053 (intptr,intptr) <0x0003b>
[art] JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[AndroidRuntime] Process: MyApplication, PID: 32611
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 1 more
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.Xml.XmlException: Text node cannot appear in this state.  Line 1, position 1.
[AndroidRuntime] at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x00028>
[AndroidRuntime] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) <0x0003f>
[AndroidRuntime] at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () <0x00027>
[AndroidRuntime] at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () <0x0003f>
[AndroidRuntime] at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) <0x0003b>
[AndroidRuntime] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.c4ebb548-a354-4444-bc7d-3e13bebb1053 (intptr,intptr) <0x0003b>
[AndroidRuntime] 
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 4 more
[Process] Sending signal. PID: 32611 SIG: 9
```

I have no idea why it happens and how to fix it. I've played with Linker Behaviour - no success. So why this can happen?